# Confused on how to use new version of Waypoints with or without jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-waypoints

I am trying to use Waypoints 3 with or without jQuery and I can't get either one to work. The documentation isn't very helpful as it mentions adapters and extensions but doesn't say which ones to load and whether to load them before or after the main waypoint.js file.

I'd like to go the jQuery route.

Here is what I have right now...

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-zepto-fn-extension.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-waypoints-adapter.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/waypoints.js"></script>
```

In a main.js file I have...

```
var waypoints = $('p.number').waypoint(function(direction) {
    console.log("I'm 25% from the top");
}, {
    offset: '25%'
});
```

And of course the html is simple...

```
<p class="number">100</p>
```

This results in the following errors...

**jquery-waypoints-adapter.js**

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'adapters' of undefined
```

**jquery-zepto-fn-extension.js**

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

Comment: Just a guess. Try to load `waypoint.js` before `jquery-waypoints-adapter.js`.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're trying to use all the source files to load the library. This is not necessary. The `lib` directory contains single-file builds for jQuery, Zepto, and no framework.

Are you using jQuery?

```
<script src="/path/to/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="/path/to/jquery.waypoints.js"></script>
```

Are you using Zepto?

```
<script src="/path/to/zepto.js"></script>
<script src="/path/to/zepto.waypoints.js"></script>
```

Are you not using either of those?

```
<script src="/path/to/noframework.waypoints.js"></script>
```